# Posting an array in jquery to the contoller returns nothing (null) in the rows

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

A dynamic table produces markup like this

```
<div>
    <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered" id="OutstandingInvoicesTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Debit</th>
                <th>Credit</th>
                <th>Pay</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>377</td>
                <td>7/9/2013</td>
                <td title='Payment on account from system'>Payment on</td>
                <td class="pTransactionRight">$0.00</td>
                <td class="pTransactionRight">$231.56</td>
                <td>
                    <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="checkbox_PaymentChecked_377"/>
                        <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
                    </label>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

The jquery to POST an array

```
//Outstanding invoices check changed
$('body').on('change', '.custom-control-input', function () {
//Send to controller to work out total of selected rows and total
var vTable = new Array();
$('#OutstandingInvoicesTable tbody tr').each(function () {
    var row = $(this);
    var rows = {};
    rows.ID = row.find("td").eq(0).html();
    rows.Debit = row.find("td").eq(3).html();
    rows.Credit = row.find("td").eq(4).html();
    rows.Selected = row.find("input").eq(0).prop('checked');
    //alert(rows.Selected);
    vTable.push(rows);

});
jQuery.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("SelectInvoicesValuesChanged", "Account")',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    traditional: true,
    data: JSON.stringify(vTable),
    success: function (response) {
        ModalSuccess(response);
    },

    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        ModalError(textStatus + " - " + errorThrown);
    }

})

})
```

seems to work - an alert will always return the correct values - but when it gets to the controller

```
 <HttpPost()>
    Function SelectInvoicesValuesChanged(vList() As List(Of String)) As ActionResult
        Try

            Dim vRows As Integer = vList.Count



            Return Json(vRows)
        Catch ex As Exception
            EmailError(ex, 846, PageName)
            Return Json("Error")
        End Try
    End Function
```

It returns the correct number of rows, but each one is nothing!

[image: Debug image]

Any ideas?

Comment: try changing your data: property of your ajax from data: JSON.stringify(vTable), to data: { vList: vTable},

Comment: Throws 'Internal Server Error'

Comment: did you check the value in data before pushing to controller from ajax?

Comment: alert(vTable.toString()); returns [object Object]

Comment: Your posting an array of complex objects,  not an array of `string`

Comment: I guess that is why adding a class with string/integer/Boolean properties worked? Or is there an easier way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add a class (Model)

   ```
   Public Class AccountModel


   Public Class InvoiceTransactions
   Public Property TransactionID() As String
       Get
           Return v_TransactionID
       End Get
       Set(value As String)
           v_TransactionID = value
       End Set
   End Property
   Private v_TransactionID As String

   Public Property Debit() As String
       Get
           Return v_Debit
       End Get
       Set(value As String)
           v_Debit = value
       End Set
   End Property

   Private v_Debit As String

   Public Property Credit() As String
       Get
           Return v_Credit
       End Get
       Set(value As String)
           v_Credit = value
       End Set
   End Property
   Private v_Credit As String

   Public Property Selected() As Boolean
       Get
           Return v_Selected
       End Get
       Set(value As Boolean)
           v_Selected = value
       End Set
   End Property

   Private v_Selected As Boolean

   End Class


   Public Property Transaction() As List(Of InvoiceTransactions)
   Get
       Return v_InvoiceTransactions
   End Get
   Set(value As List(Of InvoiceTransactions))
       v_InvoiceTransactions = value
   End Set
   End Property

   Private v_InvoiceTransactions As List(Of InvoiceTransactions)


   End Class
   ```
2. Modify the controller function

   ```
   <HttpPost()>
   Function SelectInvoicesValuesChanged(vList As List(Of AccountModel.InvoiceTransactions)) As ActionResult
       Try
           Dim vTotal As Decimal = 0
           Dim vRows As Integer = vList.Count
           If vRows > 0 Then
               For Each Row In vList
                   If Row.Selected = True Then
                       Dim vID As Integer = Row.TransactionID
                       Dim vDebit As Decimal = Row.Debit
                       Dim vCredit As Decimal = Row.Credit
                       vTotal += vDebit - vCredit
                   End If
               Next
           End If

           Return Json(vTotal)
       Catch ex As Exception
           EmailError(ex, 846, PageName)
           Return Json("Error")
       End Try
   End Function
   ```